# What is the "radiation sound speed" inside an accretion column?

Tags: neutron-star, pulsar, plasma-physics, accretion

I was trying to read "[A New Two-fluid Radiation-hydrodynamical Model for X-Ray Pulsar Accretion Columns](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/835/2/129)" and its follow-up [paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/835/2/130) both by West et al. and came across a quantity called "radiation sound speed", $a_r$.

It is defined as 
$$
a_{r}^{2}=\frac{\gamma_{r} P_{r}}{\rho},
$$
where $\gamma_{r}$ is the ratio of
specific heats for the radiation field, whatever that is supposed to mean, $P_{r}$ is the radiation pressure and $\rho$ the mass density.

My question now is: How can the radiation field have specific heats and a speed of sound?
I always though only compressible fluids, gases, etc.  can have that.

Comment: Radiation does not require medium for the energy transportation, but sound does. I think this equation explains how a radiation field interacts with matters, which are the medium for the sound wave.